# How can I pop something by reference?

Tags: c++, stack

I am doing a program to check for balanced brackets and parenthesis, etc. I created a char to store the info, and when I push the char it works, but it won't allow me to pop. Anyone know what I can do? Our prof gave us the header file so I cannot change it from int to char in the pop/push function. But I'm curious what I can do to make this work?

```
void push(int);
void pop(int &);

char ch,i;
IntStack x(50);
int count = 0;

while (fin>>ch)
{
if (ch == '[' || ch=='{' || ch=='(')
{
      x.push(ch);    //this works
  count++;
}

if (ch==']' || ch=='}' || ch==')')
{
  x.pop(ch);    //this brings an error, i also tried x.pop(ch&) and didnt work too
  count--;
}

}
```

Comment: `pop` expects an `int&`, you gave it a `char`. Always post your error messages, and please take the time to format your message properly, ideally including a [minimal code example](http://www.sscce.org/) as well.

Comment: To expand a little on what GManNickG said: a `char` can be implicitly converted to an `int`. But a `char` cannot be converted into a "reference to an int". That's why `push` works but `pop` doesn't.

Comment: so why would push work with a char but not pop? ahh get it now ^thanks ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an integer into pop that represents ch, then set ch according the results passed back from the integer.

```
int PopVar;
Pop(PopVar);
ch = PopVar;
```

Comment: the "ch = '0' + PopVar" seems wrong, the stored value in the stack is already correct, what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot bind a char to a non-const reference to int. Change the type of ch to int and you should be fine.

Comment: she recommended we char ch; and fin>>ch;   do you have any idea how i could make it work using her method?

Comment: Could you please explain further I do not understand your question.

Comment: Yes that is the correct way to read individual characters from an std::istream, but if you want your stack to hold int's you need to use a temporary to pop: int temp; x.pop(temp); ch = temp;

Comment: see my answer below to expand on what mauve's is saying.